# set a css attrs value using interpolation

Tags: angular

Using angular 2, how is it possible to set a css attrs value using interpolation.

I am using this syntax but it is not working correctly.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template:<div [ngStyle]="{'width': {{width}} +'%'}">})
export class AppComponent {
    private width: number = 12;  
    constructor (){}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for starters when you do inline templates you need to use the little ticks that are on the keyboard right before the 1 so it looks like this

```
template: `<div>blah</div>`
```

otherwise the browser isn't going to read it.

Next you're missing the closing div tag. You currently have

```
template: <div>
```

When it needs to be

```
template: `<div></div>`
```

Then as far as the syntax for the `ngStyle`.  It looks like you're trying to bind the attribute inside of the binding, which is extra unnecessary work, you just need to pass the name of the key you want it to draw the value from.  Seeing that you used the name of an actual css property, you might want to change it to `width1` or something to be sure it doesn't confuse the browser.  If you don't have the right syntax, but the `width` property is "read correctly" in the browser it can display some pretty funky stuff and not throw any errors, which makes it harder to detect when you're just starting.  Try making these changes and see if they work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure your template is wrapped in quotes or `,

Secondly what you're looking for is `<div [ngStyle]="{'width': width +'%'}">`without the curly braces